# FlashBuilder won't import

Tags: flash-builder

I am using FlashBuilder 4.6.

My relevant directory structure is as follows:

```
>src
+(default package)
  pandorica.as
  pandorica.mxml
+assets
+com
  comBrowse.as
  comBrowse.mxml
  comLoad.as
  comLoad.mxml
  comSave.as
  comSave.mxml
```

In the pandorica.as file I have the code:

```
   import com.comBrowse;
   import com.comLoad;
   import com.comSave;
```

For some reason the compiler throws the errors:

```
   1172: Definition com:comLoad could not be found.
   1172: Definition com:comSave could not be found.
```

The files definitely exist and are in the exact same format as the com.comBrowse file (which the compiler sees).

Any suggestions as to what could be the matter??
Thanks for your constructive answers.

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with this for FAAAAAAR too long I figured out a fix but still have no clue as to why it was happening. Flex was not allowing me to have the .as and .mxml files in the same directory. I ended up having to change the directories as follows:

```
>src
+(default package)
  pandorica.as
  pandorica.mxml
+assets
+com
  +as
    comBrowse.as
    comLoad.as
    comSave.as
  comBrowse.mxml
  comLoad.mxml
  comSave.mxml
```